Html.PagedListPager each button shows page number but can I add details of what is to be found on each page
I have a PagedListPager which navigates through several hundred items, 20 items per page. This works fine and the first and last item Ids are displayed above the row of pager buttons.
However, to make navigation easier, is there any way of getting the page buttons to display what Ids are on that page just by hovering over the button?
The current page and its range is displayed on the webpage, but, to help navigation to other pages, I would like the user to be able to hover over each button to see the range of records on each page.  I am using X.PagedList, the code that displays the pagedlist is:
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.BoAPApplicantPagedList, page => Url.Action("Applications", "BOAPAdmin", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions()

{
ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "navigation" },
LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-applicant" },
    LinkToNextPageFormat = ">",
LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "<",
DisplayLinkToIndividualPages=true,
MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay=40

The page displayed shows as:


Do you mean you want to add a hover event on the page number buttons, and the content in the hover tip is the Ids of the corresponding button? Does the hover event need to be applied to all of the buttons or just the current selection button? By the way, which nuget package you are using for PagedListPager? Could you please show us a sample which is working for you now and is ready to add the feature?

Yes, the current page and its range is displayed on the webpage, but, to help navigation to other pages, I would like the user to be able to hover over each button to see the range of records on each page.  I am using X.PagedList, the code that displays the pagedlist is:
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.BoAPApplicantPagedList, page => Url.Action("Applications", "BOAPAdmin", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions()
{
ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "navigation" },
LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-applicant" },

Firstly, this library doesn't have such feature so that we have to add hover event on each button after the page is loaded. Then we need to get the "range of records" for each page in advance, and this is the most difficult point I think. Is is possible for you to get this data? If so I think we could manually add hover event using jquery onload event.

The data is easy to get, but some clues about how to code the Javascript would be useful as I'm pretty bad at that language.

Here is an example for your reference:
First, I get the page number of each button through jQuery.
Then calculate the record range corresponding to the page number: according to the size of each page (PageSize) and the total number of records (TotalItemCount), calculate the start and end record IDs of the page.
Finally, set a hover event on each paging button and dynamically display the record range corresponding to the page number.
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@using X.PagedList
@model IPagedList<User>

@{
  
    var pageSize = Model.PageSize;
    var totalItemCount = Model.TotalItemCount;
}


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.Id</td>
                <td>@user.Name</td>
                <td>@user.Email</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


<div id="pagination">
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions
{
    ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "pagination" },
    DisplayLinkToIndividualPages = true,
    MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 10
})
</div>


<script>
    var pageSize = @Model.PageSize;
    var totalItemCount = @Model.TotalItemCount;
</script>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $('#pagination .pagination li').each(function () {
               
                var page = parseInt($(this).find('a').text());

                
                var startRecordId = (page - 1) * pageSize + 1;
                var endRecordId = Math.min(page * pageSize, totalItemCount);

                
                $(this).hover(function () {
                    $(this).find('a').attr('title', 'Display ID from ' + startRecordId + ' to ' + endRecordId);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

When I hover my mouse over the button:


Thanks for the javascript. With a few tweaks of my code that works fine, I just need to get the real Ids in an array as they are not sequential.
